# Glide cannot resolve method 'signature(StringSignature)'

Tags: android, caching, signature, android-glide

I am using glide 4.3.1

I want to call signature method but does't appears.

my code

```
Glide.with(context).load(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + imgName).into(imgView);
```

I want to do this

```
Glide.with(context).load(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + imgName).signature(new StringSignature("someVersion")).into(imgView);
```

I'm using android studio, when i put mouse over signature method i see the message: Cannot resolve method 'signature(StringSignature)'.

My build gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In glide v4 you should use `ObjectKey` (for files and urls) or `MediaStoreSignature`(for media content) instead of `StringSignature`

Answer (score 1):

You need to put this in your app gradle

> implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
>
> annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

In your Code you have to put this

```
GlideApp.with(context)
            .load(file.getAbsolutePath())
            .signature(new ObjectKey(file.getPath() + file.lastModified()))
            .fitCenter()
            // caches only the final image, after reducing the resolution
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
            .into(view);
```

Answer (score -2):

From what I understand, you wrote extension class for Glide but you're using basic Glide class. You should be using [Glide generated API](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html#using-the-generated-api)

```
GlideApp.with(fragment)
   .load(myUrl)
   .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
   .signature(new StringSignature("someVersion")) // your extension 
   .into(imageView);
```